# Datagrid - Row Details Full Width

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

How do I get the row details of the datagrid component to take up the full width of the available space in the grid?

I've tried modifying flex and width properties of different css classes, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7L3eGpYbzvd31HK0v2F?p=preview

```
<clr-datagrid>
  <clr-dg-column clrDgField="firstname">First name</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column clrDgField="lastname">Last name</clr-dg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users">
      <clr-dg-cell>{{user.firstname}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>{{user.lastname}}</clr-dg-cell>

      <my-detail *clrIfExpanded ngProjectAs="clr-dg-row-detail"></my-detail>
  </clr-dg-row>

  <clr-dg-footer>{{users.length}} items</clr-dg-footer>
</clr-datagrid>
```

---

```
@Component({
selector: "my-detail",
template: `
    <clr-dg-row-detail [clrDgReplace]="true">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-2">Lorem Ipsum:</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">Lorem Ipsum:</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
        </div>
    </clr-dg-row-detail>
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to say if this is the answer to your question. You shouldn't need to change the datagrid css to get content to take up a full row. Expandable rows can be used with content that takes up the whole row or with content that takes up space on a per column basis.

Here is a plunk with expandable rows implemented so you can swap full row content with per column content.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9cj1lE5B4dwpRSRcKXXX?p=preview

The relevant html looks like this:

```
  <clr-datagrid>
      <clr-dg-column>User ID</clr-dg-column>
      <clr-dg-column>Name</clr-dg-column>
      <clr-dg-column>Creation date</clr-dg-column>

      <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users" [clrDgItem]="user">
              <clr-dg-cell>{{user.id}}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>{{user.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>{{user.creation | date}}</clr-dg-cell>

              <!-- Example using a wrapper component -->
              <clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded>
                <ng-template [ngIf]="detail === 'default'">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in neque in ante placerat mattis id sed
                    quam. Proin rhoncus lacus et tempor dignissim. Vivamus sem quam, pellentesque aliquet suscipit eget,
                    pellentesque sed arcu. Vivamus in dui lectus. Suspendisse cursus est ac nisl imperdiet viverra. Aenean
                    sagittis nibh lacus, in eleifend urna ultrices et. Mauris porttitor nisi nec velit pharetra porttitor.
                    Vestibulum vulputate sollicitudin dolor ut tincidunt. Phasellus vitae blandit felis. Nullam posuere
                    ipsum tincidunt velit pellentesque rhoncus. Morbi faucibus ut ipsum at malesuada. Nam vestibulum felis
                    sit amet metus finibus hendrerit. Fusce faucibus odio eget ex vulputate rhoncus. Fusce nec aliquam leo,
                    at suscipit diam.
                </ng-template>

                <ng-template [ngIf]="detail === 'cols'">
                    <clr-dg-cell>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</clr-dg-cell>
                    <clr-dg-cell>Proin in neque in ante placerat mattis id sed quam.</clr-dg-cell>
                    <clr-dg-cell>Proin rhoncus lacus et tempor dignissim.</clr-dg-cell>
                    <clr-dg-cell>Vivamus sem quam, pellentesque aliquet suscipit eget, pellentesque sed arcu.</clr-dg-cell>
                    <clr-dg-cell>Vivamus in dui lectus. Suspendisse cursus est ac nisl imperdiet viverra.</clr-dg-cell>
                </ng-template>
              </clr-dg-row-detail>
          </clr-dg-row>

      <clr-dg-footer>{{users.length}} users</clr-dg-footer>
  </clr-datagrid>
```

Comment: On further investigation it seems the container for the row-details will fill the available width if row-details content is declared inline.  If row-details is implement via a custom component using ngProjectAs then the width of the details is determined by the content and doesn't automatically expand to fill the available area. This is demonstrated here. https://plnkr.co/edit/VMC9LeZy9Ro7ANwpOxiy?p=preview . Is this a bug?

Comment: Looking at your plunker above when I inspect the `row` element for each `clr-dg-cell` example the `.row` container element takes up the full width of the row. 

datagrid-row-details have this css applied to them: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clarity-angular/data/datagrid/_datagrid.clarity.scss#L72

Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what problem you are trying to solve? It seems like you want to create a multi column layout  for a row but I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, if you just want to replace the entire row you don't need to wrap your content in a clr-dg-cell compoent: https://plnkr.co/edit/Q5OAj87F5N8VeLr0Zc7O?p=preview

Comment: Hey @Jake - I think I got things sorted out. It does seem to be an issue on our end. The component is using flexbox default insteal of `flex: 1 1 auto`.

I created an issue that you can follow to track it here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1675

I also created a workaround that may help you for now: https://plnkr.co/edit/uVsLLzqcgnjTc9SXUyVG?p=preview

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks @hippeelee. Thanks for opening up an issue over of github as well.

Comment: Sure thing, happy to help.